# How to find max date year from this list of years

Tags: entity-framework

How to find max year from this list of years, So for an example if there are 2001, 2002, 2003. It should show 2003 as max year.

```
var result = _disbursementsDAL.GetFirst<DisbursementSchedule>().Process_End_Date.Year;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = _disbursementsDAL.GetAll<DisbursementSchedule>()
                              .Max(ds => dsProcess_End_Date.Year);
```

**Provided that** your data access layer has a method that returns all the `DisbursementSchedule`. I have use a method called `GetAll`. You may haven't any method called `GetAll`, but you need one that returns all the `DisbursementSchedule` objects.